# Search for filenames containing two or more occurrence of a specific string using PowerShell

Tags: string, windows, powershell, search, filenames

I would like to print all files of a directory which contain a specific string multiple times in their name (not in the file itself). Is there a way to do this with Powershell?

Edit:

This is what I have so far:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "path" -Recurse -Filter *string*`

With this I get all the files which contain that string at least once, but I only need the ones where it occures twice or more.

Comment: Yes, that's certainly possible. What have you tried so far?

Comment: Easy enough, can we see where youre struggling with in your code?

Comment: I only have this:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "path" -Recurse -Filter *string*`

This gives me all the files which contain that string at least once, but I only need the ones where it occures twice or more.

Comment: Please add this information including the code snippet to your question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I only have this: `Get-ChildItem -Path "path" -Recurse -Filter *string*`

Great!

Now all you need to do is repeat the word:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "path" -Recurse -Filter *string*string*
```

---

If the substring in question has spaces, you'll need to quote the string:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "path" -Recurse -Filter '*looking for this*looking for this*'
```

---

If the string contains wildcard character literals (like `[` or `]`), you can escape it like this:

```
$escapedString = [wildcardpattern]::Escape("string [ with special ] characters")
```

So the whole thing becomes:

```
$substring = "string we're [looking] for"
$searchTerm = [wildcardpattern]::Escape($substring)
Get-ChildItem -Path "path" -Recurse -Filter "*$searchTerm*$searchTerm*"
```

Comment: Ok this was way simpler than I thought it would be ^^' Thanks!

Comment: @DonCan94 When you know, you know ;-) You're welcome!